# shared module component reuse angular 2

Tags: angular

```
Parent Module 
|
+Shared Module - Shared Component
|
+Child Module - Child Component
|
+Child2 Module - Child2 Component
```

Say I have a simple file structure like so, how do I call `<shared-component><\shared-component>` in child component and child2 component. I want to import it into parent module and have it available to both modules without declaring it in their modules.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether or not this is possible but regardless I don't think it's a good pattern to follow. NgModules should be encapsulated. The best solution is to import the Shared module into both the Child1Module and Child2Module even though it seems repetitive.

Comment: That's where I'm confused though, what if I want to use some third party components am I supposed to declare it for every module??

Comment: Yup. If it feels like you are having to redeclare stuff in modules all the time then don't make so many modules. Before there were modules you had to import every single thing you used into each component that you used it in, modules were meant to get rid of that constant annoying repetition of imports. If you make a module for each component then you are doing things the old way and making your life harder. Honestly, there's nothing wrong with just having one giant root module for your whole app if that's what you want to do.